# Image Magick messes up alpha channel

Tags: imagemagick-convert, alpha-transparency

**EDIT 2**: Analyzed files.

After looking better at the gradient files I see how input/output signals of alpha levels are converted. This image shows how input alpha level (RED) is converted to output (BLUE), which looks clearly wrong and **maybe** is a bug. Or, maybe I'm wrong altogether and I'm doing something wrong.

[image: I/O signal conversion is not linear]

---

**EDIT**: Added files.

The original is quite messy with 40+ layers. I've reproduced the problem with a single layer in a very simple case (see files below).

The commands used are:

```sh
convert gradient.psd[0] gradient-0.png
convert gradient.psd[1] gradient-1.png
```

It looks like the `[0]` and `[1]` semantic is not clear to me. I thought that `[0]` is how to merge all layers, while `[1]` is just the first layer.

**NOTICE in gradient-0.png how conversion messed up the gradient!**

These are the files:

[gradient.psd](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3jq7ncdlof6d87u/gradient.psd?dl=0)

[gradient-0.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmm2t1vwtx633eh/gradient-0.png?dl=0)

[gradient-1.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1qu3gmjqjm8wr4/gradient-1.png?dl=0)

---

The image to the left is a PSD with multiple layers, one of which has a fading *BLACK* alpha channel ("shadow").
By painting on a layer ("backdrop") beneath the "shadow" layer, the colors are correctly darkened by it as expected.

What I do now, is convert with ImageMagick the PSD file into a PNG file, which does not have layers but an alpha channel. I expected the converter to preserve alpha channel data and, in fact, it does. But it somehow messes up the color of the pixels which become *GRAY* (or white?) instead of black.

The image to the right shows this effect. That is the resulting PNG file with a non-transparent backdrop to better show the undesired gray coloring.

[image]

The conversion command I use is as simple as it gets:

```sh
convert temp.psd[0] temp.png
```

Can someone explain what is happening? Or, better, help with converting it correctly?

I cannot use the GUI commands, this actually is an asset pipeline that will pump volumes of images like these hundreds of time, so scripting is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Post your original psd file

Comment: I did better! The gradient helps to intuitively see how linearly decresing values are "banded" and each band is half the previous. That looks suspiciously as if some bits are not correctly set/cleared.

Comment: The problem seems to be how you created the PSD file. It appears that you did not Maximize Compatibility when creating and saving the file. If I use Photoshop and just save the file as gradient2.psd and Maximize Compatibility, then when I do `convert gradient2.psd[0] result.png`, it looks fine. When I use your original gradient.psd and do `convert gradient.psd[0] result.png`, it is striped.

Comment: Thank you! I don't use photoshop, I use Krita. The export command does not have any parameters so there's no way I can change the Krita->PSD export with higher compatibility. I guess I'll have to find a workaround that doesn't rely on PSD. Thanks again for confirming that it's not a bug in ImageMagick. I love it, it's versatile and reliable for "serious" systems. Just this time I was surprised by this "feature"... but the problem is the PSD!